# Attempting to obtain properties / fields from an (anonymous class) object linq is creating

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm having trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong here.  I have some LINQ that returns an `IQuery` object, and later in the code, I'm attempting to list out the attributes returned.  This is best explained by this abbreviated code (the actual LINQ is a lot more complex and involves joins - the LINQ itself works fine):

```
public IQueryable<Object> FindAll()
{
    var query = from user in _db.Users
    select new
    {
        id = user.Id,
        is_active = user.IsActive,
        email = user.Email,
        dob = user.Dob,
        user.user_type,
    };
    return query;
}
```

Elsewhere in the code I have:

```
query.ConvertToCsv();
```

Although I have attempted to insert a `.ToList()` in that call as well.

The `ConvertToCsv` has:

```
public static string ConvertToCSV<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    var properties = typeof(TSource).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    var enumerable = source as IList<TSource> ?? source.ToList();
    if (!enumerable.Any()) return "";

    string headerString = "";

    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        headerString += (headerString.Length > 0 ? "," : "") + prop.Name;
    }
    sb.AppendLine(headerString);

    foreach (TSource item in enumerable)
    {
        string line = string.Join(",", properties.Select(p => p.GetValue(item).ToCsvValue()).ToArray());
        sb.AppendLine(line);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Note I have also tried to pull out the property names with this code:

```
PropertyInfo[] pi = typeof(TSource).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
var properties = pi.OrderBy(x => x.MetadataToken);
foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
{ etc etc }
```

In all cases, the property or field list returns an empty list, and as such, I can't iterate through the object to spit out a header row or data rows. Tracing through all the code and inspecting the variables indicates that everything is fine until I get to the `GetProperties`/`GetFields` line and the code fails.

What rookie mistake am I making?  Should I be replacing `<Object>` with something else?

Comment: I think you're trying to abuse anonymous types: *To pass an anonymous type, or a collection that contains anonymous types, as an argument to a method, you can declare the parameter as type object. However, doing this defeats the purpose of strong typing. If you must store query results or pass them outside the method boundary, consider using an ordinary named struct or class instead of an anonymous type.* ([Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx)). You definitely should create your own class for that!

Comment: Right-o.  I just figured because the debugger could do it... You should post this as the answer, esp given the clear reference to the programming guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To pass an anonymous type, or a collection that contains anonymous
>   types, as an argument to a method, you can declare the parameter as
>   type object. However, doing this defeats the purpose of strong typing.
>   If you must store query results or pass them outside the method
>   boundary, consider using an ordinary named struct or class instead of
>   an anonymous type.

by [Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx)

Create your own class and change method declaration to be `IQueryable<MyClass>` instead of `object`

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider doing something like: `db.Users.Select(u => new UserDto() { Id = user.Id, Name = ...`, where UserDto is dedicated class that has all the properties you'll need in the future? I think you lose information about properties when you cast from anonymous class to an Object. Although, I never tried to obtain member info from anonymous class

Comment: I had actually considered this, but I'd end up having to created a class for every complex join in the app that needs to be enumerated / dissected in this fashion - I was hoping for a better option.  (and thanks for the term anonymous class - gives me a few more leads on researching this)